# Why can't convert string to number

Tags: php, jquery

this error says need to convert number to string or something like that ...
$model->start_at print = '2019-02-11 05:00:00' and I want '11/02/2019 05:00:00'

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate : <?php
                $date = strtotime($model->start_at);
                $date = date('d/m/Y H:i',$date);
                echo $date;

            ?>
        });
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Comment: What is in `$model->start_at`

Comment: '2019-02-11 05:00:00'

Comment: Seems you have a problem somewhere, because the code is fine: http://codepad.org/jtetVF35

Comment: If you `var_dump($model->start_at)`, do you actually have what you think it is?

Comment: Can you share the generated JS code?

Answer (score 1):

Not

```
defaultDate: 2012-12-12
```

But

```
defaultDate: "2012-12-12"
```

So in your code:

```
defaultDate : "<?php
                $date = strtotime($model->start_at);
                $date = date('d/m/Y H:i',$date);
                echo $date;
            ?>"
```

Always check generated js code.

Answer (score 0):

by the end I finished doing this and it works thanks anyway

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:ss"
        });

                             <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Fecha y Hora de Inicio</label>
                                    <div class='input-group date'>
                                        <input type="text"  id='datetimepicker' value="<?php
                                            $date = strtotime($model->start_at);
                                            $date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$date);
                                            echo $date  ?>," class="form-control"  name="start_at" required>
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

defaultDate should be in double citation like this:

```
defaultDate: "2012-12-12"
```

So your code should looks like below:

```
defaultDate : "<?php $date = strtotime($model->start_at); $date = date('d/m/Y H:i',$date); echo $date; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly quote the values. You current code would result in:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   defaultDate : 11/02/2019 05:00:00
})
```

And thats not valid JavaScript.

You should use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to correctly encode the value into a format that is valid in JavaScript:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  defaultDate : <?php
    $date = strtotime($model->start_at);
    $date = date('d/m/Y H:i',$date);
    echo json_encode($date);
  ?>
});
```

And as `json_encode` not only correctly encodes strings, but also numbers, booleans, arrays, associative arrays, it would also allow to build the options object completely in php. This is useful if you have multiple or optional properties that you calculate in php.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(<?php
   $params = array();
   $date = strtotime($model->start_at);
   $params['defaultDate'] = date('d/m/Y H:i',$date);

   echo json_encode($params);
?>)
```